# Why do I get TypeError when trying to do dot product?

Tags: python-3.x, dot-product

If I have one integer and multiply it by each integer in a container (tuple) and add them together -- similar to a dot product -- I get the right answer.  When I convert them to floats, I get a TypeError:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
sig = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}
exp = {'a': (1.0,2.0,3.0), 'b': (1.0,2.0,3.0), 'c': (1.0,2.0,3.0)}
man_dot = {'a': 1*1+1*2+1*3, 'b': 2*1+2*2+2*3, 'c': 3*1+3*2+3*3}

weighted_dict = {}
for s in sig:
    print("this is s:\n{}".format(s))
    for e in exp:
        print("this is e:\n{}".format(e))
        weighted_dict[s] = sum(sig[s] * exp[e])
# weighted_dict should be equivalent to man_dot
# weighted_dict should be {'a': 6, 'c': 18, 'b': 12}
```

This script must handle operation with floats, so how can I modify it to do so?  Why does this happen? Is there a better of of doing this with some math-oriented library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to multiply `(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)` by `1.0`, which gives the aforementioned error. Try the following:

```
sig = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}
exp = {'a': (1.0,2.0,3.0), 'b': (1.0,2.0,3.0), 'c': (1.0,2.0,3.0)}
man_dot = {'a': 1*1+1*2+1*3, 'b': 2*1+2*2+2*3, 'c': 3*1+3*2+3*3}

weighted_dict = {}
for s in sig:
    print("this is s:\n{}".format(s))
    for e in exp:
        print("this is e:\n{}".format(e))
        weighted_dict[s] = sum([sig[s] * item for item in exp[e]])
```

---

```
>>> weighted_dict
{'c': 18.0, 'a': 6.0, 'b': 12.0}
>>>
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thanks.  So the issue was I was failing to iterate through the tuple values of {exp}.  But why does it work with integers but not floats?